# Add wildcard urls in the Azure AD App redirect url

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, wildcard-subdomain, azure-app-registration

I have developed an application which will be consumed by more than 500 customers. The application is deployed in the IIS and configured subdomain for each customer to access the application, like

https://customer1.app.com

https://customer2.app.com

https://customer3.app.com

I have integrated the Azure AD B2C authentication to the application, all the users of the customer will be in the single AD B2C tenant.

I need to add the redirect url in the App for all the customers, so that after authentication the user will be navigate back to the respective sub domains.

There is a restriction in the limit of the redirect url, only 256 urls can be added in the App.

The app is created with account type `"Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)"` as I have integrated Azure AD federated authentication.

Is there any way to add wildcard urls in the app like https://*.demo.com? or

Is there any way to Azure team can explictly increase the limit for my app?

Answer (score 1):

> Note that, Azure AD B2C currently **does not support** wildcard redirect URIs whereas you can add them to applications with Supported account type other than **userflows** via CLI.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD B2C application with **same** account type and tried to add **wildcard URLs** in it from Portal, where I got **error** like this:

[image]

Now, I registered another application with **Supported account type** as `Multi-tenant` and got **same error** when I tried to add wildcard URLs from Portal like this:

[image]

I ran below **CLI commands** to add wildcard URLs in that application like this:

```
az login --tenant <b2ctenantID>
az ad app update --id <b2cappID> --web-redirect-uris "https://*.demo.com"
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **wildcard URL** added successfully to application under `Redirect URIs` like below:

[image]

If you want to explicitly increase the limit, you can reach out to Azure Support team with proper justification.

Comment: Thank you, let me try adding the urls using CLI and share the feedback